# Display On when plugged in

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, screen, standby

Is there a way to keep the display "ON" whilst the device is plugged in?

I am running Android 2.2 Froyo on Samsung Galaxy S.

Comment: What device do you have?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy S

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Settings > Applications > Development > Stay awake

Comment: This function is missing in Froyo 2.2 update 1.

Comment: @Cooler77: I see it on my Droid. What device are you using?

Comment: Does this limit "Stay awake" to when the device is plugged in, or will it also keep it awake when it's on the battery?

Comment: @Nathan Fellman as the feature description says "Screen will never sleep while charging"

Comment: @mlevit: then I have no choice but to vote this answer up...