# How do I disable the lock-screen when my Samsung Galaxy S II is charging/connected via USB?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, lock-screens, charging

When I develop for my Samsung Galaxy S II, the screen locks as usual after the configured time. However, for development it would be practical if the phone would just stay awake while it is connected to my computer.

So, 
**How do I disable the lock-screen when my Samsung Galaxy S II is charging/connected via USB?**

Question: [Display On when plugged in](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4667/display-on-when-plugged-in) is not a duplicate, as this solution does not work on the Galaxy S II. Unfortunately.

Comment: @Al Everett: Solution from "duplicate" does not work on Galaxy S II. I am looking specifically for solutions anybody may have found on the Galaxy S II. Please reopen?

Comment: Carriers and OEMs _really_ need to stop messing with basic settings like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the app [StayAwake](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.gmail.developer.runks.enji), it should work for Galaxy S II too.